# Creating a Tag Helper from within a Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project that has quite a lot of tag helpers, that just render a view, effectively treating them like components. The reason we're not using Razor components is mainly because we can't use tag helpers in them (not just for our stuff but for links, forms etc.). It gives us a similar experience to Razor components and I quite like it, but for each "component" we always need to create a backing class to register the tag helper.

What I would really like is to not have to create that backing class but just register the tag helper from within the view, bringing it closer to Razor components with their `@parameter`.

I've tried a few things:

- Creating the class in an `@functions` block in the view. This isn't picked up, I think because it is created as a nested class. But also because this is compiled into a C# class so I'm guessing Razor cant know about the tag helper that exists within it?
- We import tag helpers in the `_ViewImports` file, but I also toyed with `ApplicationPart` and feature providers in an attempt to register my "generated" tag helper manually, but I had no joy there.
- I created a source generator that pulls the tag helper class out of the first `@functions` directive and basically creates a copy of this. This needs to happen in a separate project that is referenced by the web project because otherwise Razor wont pick it up (unless we change to the old two-step process). But regardless, this doesn't feel like a great solution regardless.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this "single file component" with tag helpers? Or any ideas to achieve a similarly satisfactory dev experience?

Comment: Can you please share the code you've written so far?

Comment: Could you show your target more clearly?